# Hadoop MapReduce Count and display the Max value

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

If I want to write a "word count" program to find which character has the largest number, my Reducer class will be like this:

```
private String maxWord;
private int max = 0; 

@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
    long sum = 0;
    for (LongWritable value : values) 
    {
        sum += value.get();
    }

    if(sum > max)
    {
        max = sum;
        maxWord.set(key);
    }
}

// only display the character which has the largest value
@Override
protected void cleanup(Context context) {
    context.write(new Text(maxWord), new LongWritable(max)));
}
```

But after running my program, it always gives me an error which is "NullPointerException" in Recuder Task, I don't understand why. How I improve my program to achieve this goal?

Comment: Please provide the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try initializing your instance variables in the setup() method. Off the top of my head, can you even call String.set() before you've initialized the string?  That would do it.

As noted in comments, a stacktrace would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is it:

```
  public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
  int max =0;
  Text maxWord = new Text();

      public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          int sum=0;
          for (IntWritable value : values) 
            {
                sum += value.get();
            }

            if(sum > max)
            {
                max = sum;
                maxWord.set(key);
            }

  }

  @Override
  protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      context.write(maxWord, new IntWritable(max));
  }
}
```